# Does sleep duration vary for animals based on time of the year?

Tags: zoology, sleep, circadian-rhythms, melatonin

I'm interested in the sleep patterns of wild animals, that still use sun for controlling their biological clock.

Animals entrain their biological clock to the day/night cycle using light as the entrainment signal. The biological clock follows the day/night cycle: dim light initiates melatonin secretion, while bright morning light stops melatonin production. [Melatonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melatonin) is involved in sleep regulation

Here, I have plotted the day duration over the course of the year for Northeast US, around Washington DC.

My question is **given the day duration plot below, would the total sleep duration for wild animals vary over the course of the year?**

In other words, would animals sleep longer in the winter time and shorter in the summer time?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, people, as well as animals regulate their drowsiness by light. There's a well known experiment conducted by [Michel Suffre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Siffre) on himself in 1972. When he spent a month with no light and no information about the time, his sleeping cycles prolonged up to 48 hours.